# Mounting main partition read-only and temporary folders as tmpfs

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, fstab, embedded

I have a small embedded board PC which uses flash card to boot and I'm running Ubuntu server 12.04. But since flash cards have limited lifetime I would like to mount it as read only and have only some folders in tmpfs for file operations.

I edited my fstab as follows:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
UUID=0b2dc455-4dd0-4a4f-934c-587962b006c8 / ext4 ro,discard,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
tmpfs /tmp      tmpfs nodev,nosuid      0       0
tmpfs /var/log  tmpfs nodev,nosuid      0       0
```

But since the system is read-only it doesn't mount tmpfs folders. Is there any way I can mount tmpfs on read-only filesystem?

**EDIT**

`df -h` looks like this after startup:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p2  7.4G  2.0G  5.5G  27% /
udev            450M  4.0K  450M   1% /dev
none            453M     0  453M   0% /run/shm
```

Comment: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /tmp` should work

Comment: Nope, no error is printed, but it doesn't appear in `df -h`

Comment: run `mount` to verify

Comment: run as `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o remount,rw /tmp` and check using `mount`